# how to R create a data frame from a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list with multiples elements

```
L

[[749]]
       Element     Element.1 
       "EE0792"    "EE_RS04065" 

[[750]]
       Element     Element.1 
       "EE0793"    "EE_RS04070" 

[[751]]
       Element     Element.1
       "EE0794"    "EE_RS04075"
```

so, I want to make a data frame using the old_locus_tag and old_locus_tag.1 as column
I tried something like:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(L), nrow=length(L), byrow=TRUE))
```

but I got all the data in a single row (1):

```
df[1:3,1:3]
         X1         X2     X3
1    EE0001 EE_RS00280 EE0002
NA     <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
NA.1   <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
```

I want to get something like (if there is any empty row add an NA )

```
   Element          Element.1
   EE0792           EE_RS04065
   EE0793           EE_RS04070
   EE0794           EE_RS04075
   EE0795           NA
   EE0796           EE_RS04077
```

thanks so much

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, L)`

Comment: I already did, and when I tried to convert to data.frame I got the same !!!

Comment: With the example you showed, it is working fine for me i.e. `rbind` by default gives a matrix and you can wrap with `as.data.frame` to make it data.frame or use `rbind.data.frame`

Comment: When you say empty row, did you meant `NULL`, not clear though

Comment: yes I tried, df <- do.call(rbind, L) and then df <- as.data.frame(df), and it give me the same as the first example, all the data in the first row (1), and I used df <- rbind.data.frame(df) and it give me the same. Sorry, yes it's " NULL ". Thanks

Comment: Please consider to provide a small reproducible example that shows the issue.  Otherwise, people cannot understand your actual issue

Comment: If you have `NULL` elements try `library(purrr); map_dfr(L, ~ if(is.null(.x)) tibble(Element = NA_character_, Element.1 = NA_character_) else as_tibble(.x))`